# Mac QGIS files to Windows Arc GIS compatibility

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, mac

If I download QGIS on to Mac will the shapefiles and layers I create be compatible with ESRI ArcGIS 10.1 on windows?

Comment: Please define what you mean by 'layers'.

Answer (score 5):

If you are asking if a shapefile that is created with QGIS in a Mac environment will open with ESRI in a Windows environment, the answer is yes. A shapefile is a file format. It will respond to software the same, regardless of operating system. Think of it like a JPEG. You can make JPEGs on a Mac, and view them in Windows, or Linux.